# How to interpret the assembly boot code with ".word"

Tags: assembly, arm, cortex-m, thumb

I'm slowly studying in step by step the boot code within assembly.

I found the below assembly boot code. but I've still problem to understand completely.

So far, as I understood,

First of all, after line 1 execute,

then go to line 2,

then  go to line 5,

then  go to line 6, load 0x40002001 to r1 register,

then  go to line 7, branch to r1's register address ( PC is updated as 0x40002001)

till here what I understood.

But I can't understand line 3 and line 4's purpose and meaning .

Would you please let me know what are line 3 and 4 having a meaning and purpose?

```
1    .section .text                                                             
2        .globl main

3        .word   0x40002000 
4        .word   main+1

5     main:                                                                      
6         ldr   r1, st0                                                       
7         bx    r1           

8        .align 4
9     st0:                                                                   
10       .word   0x40002001
```

Comment: You should not think of lines 1, 2, and 5 as being executed. The only executable instructions here are lines 6 and 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the documentation for the cortex-m3.  This is from ARM's website not necessarily the chip vendors.

The short answer is the .words are there to describe the vector table, these are not instructions.  The .align whose arguments meaning can vary, is there to make sure the constant is aligned right to avoid a data abort.

The first item/word at address 0x00000000 is a value loaded into the stack pointer on reset.  The second word is the reset vector.  Being a thumb instruction set machine this wants to have an address with the lsbit set in the vector table.

Then the code branches to 0x40002000 the lsbit is stripped off but is necessary for the bx to work. (the PC gets 0x40002000 not 0x40002001)

You didnt specify the assembly language (assembler), if this is going to use gnu assembler then you can clean it up some:

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

    .globl _start
_start:
    .word   0x40002000
    .word   main

    .thumb_func
main:
     ldr   r1, st0
     bx    r1

    .align
st0:
    .word   0x40002001
```

Producing

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   40002000    andmi   r2, r0, r0
   4:   00000009    andeq   r0, r0, r9

00000008 <main>:
   8:   4900        ldr r1, [pc, #0]    ; (c <st0>)
   a:   4708        bx  r1

0000000c <st0>:
   c:   40002001    andmi   r2, r0, r1
```

Now the question is how are you getting the program into memory at 0x40002000 before reset?

You can do this trick in gnu assembler to the .align confusion or possible waste (of using the wrong value after .align)

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

    .globl _start
_start:
    .word   0x40002000
    .word   main

    .thumb_func
main:
     ldr   r1, =0x40002001
     bx    r1

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   40002000    andmi   r2, r0, r0
   4:   00000009    andeq   r0, r0, r9

00000008 <main>:
   8:   4900        ldr r1, [pc, #0]    ; (c <main+0x4>)
   a:   4708        bx  r1
   c:   40002001    andmi   r2, r0, r1
```

the alignment is to avoid something like this causing a fault:

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

    .globl _start
_start:
    .word   0x40002000
    .word   main

    .thumb_func
main:
     nop
     ldr   r1, st0
     bx    r1

.align
st0: .word 0x40002001
```

the .align caused padding to be added where above it didnt need to because the value landed in a place it was aligned.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   40002000    andmi   r2, r0, r0
   4:   00000009    andeq   r0, r0, r9

00000008 <main>:
   8:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
   a:   4901        ldr r1, [pc, #4]    ; (10 <st0>)
   c:   4708        bx  r1
   e:   bf00        nop

00000010 <st0>:
  10:   40002001    andmi   r2, r0, r1
```

this also aligns for you, pads with zeros in this case, didnt use an align, let it place the data in a pool

```
.cpu cortex-m3
.thumb

    .globl _start
_start:
    .word   0x40002000
    .word   main

    .thumb_func
main:
     nop
     ldr   r1, =0x40002001
     bx    r1
```

It doesnt disassemble well so the intel hex output form shows what happened.

```
:100000000020004009000000C046014908470000E8
:04001000012000408B
:00000001FF
```

same as above but the padding is 0x0000

```
0x4708 (bx r1)
0x0000
0x40002001
```